# How to Return a bool method with string parameter in Main Method

Tags: c#

I have created a bool method with a string parameter. while value true it works, on false it gives an error.
When calling the bool method in the main method, it does not accept the same string parameter from bool method.

```
public static bool init_access(string file_path)
{

    int counter = 0;
    file_path = @"C:\Users\waqas\Desktop\TextFile.txt";
    List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(file_path).ToList();
    foreach (string line in lines)

    {

        counter++;
        Console.WriteLine(counter + " " + line);
    }
    if (File.Exists(file_path))
    {

        return (true);

    }

    return false;
}
```

If a file does exist it should return true else it should return false.

Comment: Your code always reads the same file and because it exists it always returns true

Comment: if the file doesn't exit, you read then because `` List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(file_path).ToList();`` is before your ``File.Exists()`` method. So it's normal you have an error because read a file that doesn't exist throw an error

Comment: You can figure out what's wrong with this by stepping through your code in the debugger.

Comment: @GabrielLuci: Or even just by reading the code carefully...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "on false it gives an error" - possibly just by giving details of what error you are seeing (and whether it is a compiler error, a runtime error or something else). Also the question could do with more detail on "it does not accept the same string parameter from bool method". What do you mean it doesn't accept it? If a method accepts a string then it shouldn't matter what that string is in terms of the method accepting it... Can you give details of what error or similar you are getting?

Answer (score 6):

You first read the file and then you check if it exists. Of course you have to use the other way:

```
public static bool init_access(string file_path)
{
    if (!File.Exists(file_path))
    {
        return false;
    }

    int counter = 0;
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file_path);
    foreach (string line in lines)    
    {   
        counter++;
        Console.WriteLine(counter + " " + line);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    public static bool init_access(string file_path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(file_path))
        {
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(file_path))
            {
                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine(counter + " " + line);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If you use it directly in the `foreach` loop i'd prefer `File.ReadLines(file_path)` over `File.ReadAllLines(file_path).ToList()` which creates two unnecessary collections. I'd also prefer returning early instead of nesting code. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement

Answer (score 1):

In general (or *paranoic*) case file can appear / disapper (be created or deleted) just *after* the `File.Exists` check. Catching *exception* (`FileNotFoundException`) is sure but *slower* way:

```
public static bool init_access(string file_path)
{
    try 
    {
        foreach (string item in File
              .ReadLines(file_path)
              .Select((line, index) => $"{index + 1} {line}"))
            Console.WriteLine(item);

        return true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException) 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rango said, yes, you will have to check if the file exists first. And if you like smaller solutions:

```
public static bool init_access(string file_path)
{
    if (File.Exists(file_path))
    {
        var counter = 0;
        File.ReadAllLines(file_path).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(counter++ + " " + x));

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```